# Equation Editor in Word generates images instead of editable objects?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, equations, equation-editor

I am using Microsoft Word 2008 on Mac OS X 10.6.3.  I save my documents as .Doc format, compatible with Word 2004.  I found that when I make equations using Equation Editor and then reopen the document, they appear as IMAGES instead of editable Equation Editor objects.  How can I prevent this from happening?  Also, is there a way to convert those images into objects?  They were made purely within Equation Editor so I am hoping there's a way to go back...

thanks.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Word 08 on my Mac and saving them as .docx and having the same problem...I make equations using Equation Editor and then reopen the document, they appear as IMAGES instead of editable Equation Editor objects.

Answer (score 1):

The older `.doc` format doesn't support the equation objects, so they have to be converted in to something `.doc` *does* support - namely images.

Is there a reason you cannot use the newer `.docx` format?

Note that I've just tested something and, in Word2007 on Windows, writing an equation and saving as `.doc`, closing Word, then reopening the file and saving back to `.docx` will re-enable the equation for editing again.

So, try converting your files to `.docx` to see if that allows you to re-edit the equation. You could even convert the files *back* to `.doc` afterwards, but there might be some issues with the layout or other elements so test this first.

Comment: It is not possible to use .docx in my case.  The publishers only accept Word 2004.

Comment: @user That's a pain. Anyway, did you try converting the files to `docx` temporarily to see if that does enable you to then edit the equation?